# How to implement retransmissions in Twisted UDP-based application

Tags: timeout, udp, twisted

I want to write a UDP based app which needs to retransmit packets that are not confirmed by remote host. I assume there are two possible approaches:

1. Use reactor.callLater() for every packet sent by my application, to call a function which checks if confirmation has been received (and retransmits the packet if it hasn't).
2. Remember every packet in a special list and periodically call a function which checks all members of this list if confirmation has been received for them. This function would also be called through reactor.callLater() - with timeout set to the next retransmission (shortest value for all packets in the list).

My questions are:

1. First approach is much simpler - but is Twisted underlying implementation efficient enough to use it?
2. When using second approach is it possible to interrupt reactor.callLater()? For example if I have a call scheduled for 20 seconds, and suddenly I need to send a new packet with retransmission interval of 5 seconds?

Best Regards

Maciek

Comment: Consider using TCP which will handle retransmission for you.

Comment: I'm working on [CoAP Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Application_Protocol) which is used on top of UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of discussing the behavior of `callLater`, I'll ignore the UDP part of this question and answer the two specific questions you've asked. :)

Handling of delayed calls is efficient.  Scheduling a single new call is O(log N) on the number of already scheduled calls.  Overall reactor performance is constant on the number of scheduled calls.

As far as "interrupting" goes, "interrupt" is the wrong word for what you want.  [Delayed calls can be rescheduled](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IDelayedCall.html) using either `reset` or `delay`.  And, of course, you could always `cancel` an existing call and schedule a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much Jean-Paul - that convinces me that picking up Twisted was a good choice.
Best Regards